# Toolvalidator script is not working in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, geoprocessing-service, tool-validation

I have made a small GP tool in ArcMap, which is also having some validation code in tool validator class. And it is working fine as GP tool in ArcGIS desktop(Arcmap). But when i published the same tool as Geo-Processing service added as toolbox in ArcMap, it is not considering any validations.
Ex: Disable/Enable some textboxes.

What should i do to integrate these validations in GP service also?

Answer (score 1):

There is some documentation which I am assuming that you are unaware of because you do not reference it in your question.

I encourage you to read the page entitled [Authoring geoprocessing tasks with Python scripts](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00570000007r000000), and in particular the section headed **Tool validation code** which says:

> If you have experience writing script tools, you may be providing your
>   own tool validation logic. Clients of geoprocessing service do not
>   have the capability to execute your tool validation logic—only the
>   server has this capability.

I have only done some rudimentary tool validation on the desktop, and have not attempted it on a geoprocessing service, but the documentation linked above suggests that there are methods for **Making project data and modules tool parameters** that may assist you.